# Происхождение слова "русич"

Tags: этимология

Почему по отношению к русским используют определение "русич", если данный термин нигде в летописях не встречается, а суффикс -ич не характерен для русского языка. Каково происхождение данного слова?

Answer (score 2):

Русич, вятич, княжич... Почему же суффикс -ич не характерен для русского языка?  Очень даже характерен! А, может, нехарактерен потому, что его комп красным подчёркивает?)))

Answer (score 2):

От кого произошли вятичи, кривичи, петровичи, ивановичи?  Они произошли от Вятко, Кривия, Петра и Ивана. Все они - русские, то есть люди, принадлежавшие к буйному варяжскому племени русов. Так что русич - это не рус, а тот, у кого среди  предков лет тысячу назад этот рус наличествовал.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, что такое "почему"? Потому, что это слово вошло в язык. Напоминает вопрос "Почему кошку назвали кошкой?"

Во-вторых, в вашем вопросе содержится ошибочная информация.
Для начала: "ич" - типичный для русского суффикс притяжательности. Для этнохоронимов древнерусских племен - просто таки единственный.

И главное. Слово "русич" есть в "Слове о полку Игореве". 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8
(вики)

Там же - и обсуждение.

Да, "Происхождение" Топоним "Русь" + "ич". Типичнейший словообразовательный метод. Обсуждать можно только его древность, оспариваемую некоторыми авторами, считающими "Слово" подделкой. Я не сторонник этой версии. Но это все есть по ссылке в Вики.

Comment: Прошу внимательно читать вопрос! Во-первых: почему к русским,а не например к русинам (украинцам)? Во-вторых,откуда в русском языке суффикс -ич,если для русского языка характерен только -ов: Иванов,Петров,которые пришли в  русский язык из болгарского языка. В-третьих,"Слово о полку Игореве" это не летопись,а литературное произведение т.е. подделка.

Comment: 1. Если вы хотите уточнить вопрос, используете правку, а не комментарии. 2. Формат  ресурса не предполагает ведение дискуссии, тем более -  в подобном тоне. 3. "Русины" - не украинцы по национальности, а всего лишь жители Украины. Но это не важно. Слово "русин" - в древнерусском это синоним "русича". Т.е.  может  с той или иной достоверностью относиться к любому из древнерусских племен, в т. ч. и к предкам современных украинцев. Современное использование его в рекламных и политических целях - за рамками лингвистического обсуждения. 4. Про "подделку" уже сказал. Не согласен.